# Groovy getter/setter shorthand notation and API changes

Tags: java, groovy, integration, getter-setter

I have inherited a large groovy application that relies on an API written in Java. The groovy application uses shorthand getter and setter methods for things in the Java API:

```
context.getItem().getValue().getNodeName().getText() [java]
context.item.value.nodeName.text [groovy]
```

The Java API is rapidly being developed and frequently has changes.

This poses a problem because changes in the Java API do not show up as errors in the groovy code when it compiles; integration testing becomes useless. Instead, they become runtime exceptions.

Aside from unit testing, is there any way I can pinpoint where all these getter and setter methods are called, or find things that would become possible errors? How do other people address this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "integration testing becomes useless",
but yes, as you have discovered, a major difference between static and dynamic languages is that some things that are compile-time errors in static languages become run-time errors in dynamic languages.

The typical solution is indeed heavier reliance on testing, both unit testings and integration tests. For this reason, TDD (test-driven design) is heavily adopted by folks working with dynamic languages.

One thing that *may* help is "Groovy++", a statically-typed extension of the Groovy language. See http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/

Comment: +1 for groovy++. Declaring the types as "static" should lead to an increase in performance as well as picking up errors at compile time.

Comment: I suppose I meant that simple nightly builds of all components, which have worked in the past to ensure that our code is functional on a basic level, no longer work (continuous integration builds). I am very new to mixing static- and dynamic-typed languages; so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As GreyBeardedGeek [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387972/581845), testing will help a lot in this regard. In fact, I think the more thoroughly you test you application, the more confident you are going to be about your refactorings (or API changes) are not breaking anything, and it will feel great :)

However, **good tooling** will help too. Intellij IDEA has some awesome Groovy code inspection/refactoring capabilities. It does a very good job at infering the types of expressions, so most of the times refactoring will Just Work™.

Comment: I'm using eclipse with the Groovy plugin. Other developers are using IntelliJ but only as an editor. The problem is convincing them to use the refactoring tools. :)